# Android Service continues to disconnect when closing the application

Tags: java, android

I had previously managed to get my service to continue running. But today after I went back to the application to keep working with the app I noticed that the service gets disconnected after the app is closed which was not happening before.

I start the service in my main activity like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent i  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SystemWebService.class);
            SystemWebService.setMain(this);
            MainActivity.this.startService(i);

        }
```

The code in the SystemWebService class looks like this:

```
 public class SystemWebService extends Service {

        private static WebView webdemo;
        private static MainActivity ma;
        //Context dex;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public  int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
            // let the service continue until stopped
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service has started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service has been destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

        }

        public static void setMain(MainActivity a) {
            ma = a;
            SystemWebService sws = new SystemWebService();
            sws.setView();
        }
}
```

This is the code that sets the webview

```
public  void setView() {
        webdemo = (WebView) ma.findViewById(R.id.webdemo);
        webdemo.addJavascriptInterface(new SystemWebService.WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        webdemo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest url){
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            webdemo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webdemo.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webdemo.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webdemo.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        webdemo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/_wv.html");
    }
```

The webview establishes a connection to our server and I would normally see data display on the logs. Before I would continue to see the flux of data passing even after the application was closed but as of right not I am not seeing anything, only the message "Application terminated".

I can't seem to understand what is happening.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I think its because onCreate() methos is empty. So the os destroys the service once the app is closed. also the setMain() method is not called .

Comment: @JerinAMathews even with the onStartCommand() method in place? The onDestroy() method never activates by the way. I never see the toast saying "services has been destroyed" the only indication of the service being destroyed is what appears on the Android Studio Run logs. would that mean that the app is in actuality not destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference of your activity to the service, and keeping a static instance of it is not the recommended way of development. It can lead to unexpected behaviour during the life cycle of your activity or the service.

Use the Bound Services instead. Check the documentation here : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have looked into this before but could not find a point of reference to use other than the docs. I can't figure out how would I use the above code for this

Comment: Great suggestion, but this doesn't provide a specific answer to the specific question. Can you identify why the issue in the question is occurring and why your solution helps prevent it? If this is just a general suggestion it would be a great use for the Comment feature but you must have 50 reputation in order to post comments to questions.